# How too add Minutes to datetime in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to add 10 minutes to the datetime "2011-09-23 15:56:39.2370000" in pyspark.(primary motive for my project). But dateadd doesnt work here.

I tried this:

```
%%spark 

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from datetime import datetime

query = """Select 
                    Id,
                    clientid,
                    datetimeA
                    CASE
                        When 
                            datetimeB between datetimeA and dateadd(minute, 10,'datetimeA')
                        Then
                            datetimeB
                        Else
                            Null END       AS DatetimeB


            from 
                    TABLE_A 
                """

queryDF = spark.sql(query)
```

But didn't work.

The required output is:

```
ID | Clientid |              DateTimeA            |             DateTimeB              |
1       123     "2011-09-23 15:56:39.2370000"           "2011-09-23 15:58:39.2370000"
2       124     "2011-09-23 15:56:39.2370000"                       null (if the datetime is beyong 10 minutes)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INTERVAL`:

```
spark.sql("""SELECT current_timestamp() AS now, current_timestamp() + INTERVAL 10 MINUTES AS add_ten_min""").show(2,False)
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|now                    |add_ten_min            |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|2019-09-23 12:36:44.424|2019-09-23 12:46:44.424|
+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: in that case, this function will give the wrong result if date-time is greater than 23:50:44.424 because it will change the date to next day date

Comment: @MaheshGupta Isn’t it correct? It should go to next date. As per question, user want to add 10 minutes to DATE-time not just the time.

Comment: Thats correct, I want 10 minutes to be added, which would eventually change the date. That should be fine.